# Nginx directs me to the wrong site

Tags: linux, spring, http, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm building this website and as web server I'm using Nginx. For this website I've got multiple configurations, one for implementing a java springboot application, the others are for static websites. In total there are three configs for Nginx to load. I've proceeded to create them in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available` folder, then linked all of the with the command `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/<config> .` and all the links were made correctly. I've refresh the configuration with both `sudo nginx -s reload` and `sudo systemctl restart nginx` . Then i checked the configuration with the command `sudo nginx -T` and the output was the following (only linking the important part for now):

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/annunci:
# ANNOUNCEMENTS WEBSITE

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name "dev.redacted.it";

        root /var/www/annunci;

        location / {
                autoindex       on;
        }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/main:
# MAIN WEBSITE

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name "redacted.it";

        root /var/www/html;

        location / {
                index index.html;
        }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ticket:
# TICKET WEBSITE

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name "tickets.redacted.it";

        ssl_certificate /home/dev/cert/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /home/dev/cert/private.key;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

The problem is that even with the following config, when i try reach the `http://dev.redacted.it` website, it gives me the `https://tickets.redacted.it` website, but when i try only `http://redacted.it` then it shows the website it should show (the one in the config). I don't know how to solve this bug or what causes it.

I've tried everything I could, but nothing seemed to work. I tried at one point comparing the permissions and ownerships of the two static websites folders but they were exactly the same (755 | root:root). The `http://redacted.it` website worked whilst the `http://dev.redacted.it` directed me to the `https://tickets.redacted.it` one instead. I tried working with custom ports instead of flooding the *:80 port but nothing seemed to improve and I wasn't seeing my site at all. The configuration gives no error whenever I refresh it, whether I used `sudo systemctl restart nginx` or `sudo nginx -s reload`. I'm was left with no other option other from the internet, but even here I couldn't find a single post or solution that matched my problem and I even tried some although it looked like they were going to do absolutely nothing but still no progress was made. What can I do?

Comment: You should test your website using `curl -I http://dev.redacted.it` to double check that Nginx is not the problem. Often this is caused by the browser caching an old [HSTS header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). Try `curl` then try resetting your browser.

Comment: The access log should show what the client requested

Comment: I've tried curl and I think it is nginx problem, because I tried with 3 different browsers, even a cli one, all cleared and fresh but I still couldn't visit the page